# Ansible plugin in callback_plugins directory runs multiple times

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am running the following ansible script to be able to deploy my Java project with ansible:

```
ansible-playbook -u ansible -i inventory/test-env release.yml
```

I added [this plugin](https://github.com/jlafon/ansible-profile) under my callback_plugins directory under ansible.
The problem is whenever I run the **ansible-playbook** script, the logging in this plugin runs multiple times at the end and it is not consistent. Sometimes I get the logs twice and sometimes three times.

Do you have any idea why it may occurs and why the number of logs changes every time?

I have read that if the naming of a plugin is the same as an existing plugin in the ansible itself it might cause this issue. Therefore, I changed the name of this plugin to something else in my project.

**Note that** my ansible version is: 2.4.2

This is the output I am getting:

```
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
def1.test1.domain.com : ok=101  changed=31   unreachable=0    failed=0   
def2.test1.domain.com : ok=70   changed=20   unreachable=0    failed=0   
abc1.test1.domain.com : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
abc2.test1.domain.com : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

copy domain to managed servers ----------------------------------------- 97.00s
start managed servers -------------------------------------------------- 82.62s
wait for admin server to start ----------------------------------------- 31.64s
create domain ---------------------------------------------------------- 25.97s

Playbook finished: Wed Jan 30 11:09:04 2019, 114 total tasks.  0:06:17 elapsed. 

copy domain to managed servers ----------------------------------------- 97.00s
start managed servers -------------------------------------------------- 82.62s
wait for admin server to start ----------------------------------------- 31.64s
create domain ---------------------------------------------------------- 25.97s

Playbook finished: Wed Jan 30 11:09:04 2019, 114 total tasks.  0:06:17 elapsed. 

copy domain to managed servers ----------------------------------------- 97.00s
start managed servers -------------------------------------------------- 82.62s
wait for admin server to start ----------------------------------------- 31.64s
create domain ---------------------------------------------------------- 25.97s

Playbook finished: Wed Jan 30 11:09:04 2019, 114 total tasks.  0:06:17 elapsed.
```

At the beginning of the logs, I caught this:

```
setting up inventory plugins
Parsed /var/go/pipelines/abc/inventory/test inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.pyc
Loading callback plugin unnamed of type old, v1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.pyc
Loading callback plugin unnamed of type old, v1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.pyc
Loading callback plugin unnamed of type old, v1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.pyc

PLAYBOOK: release.yml **********************************************************
11 plays in release.yml

PLAY [install weblogic] ********************************************************
```

Comment: An example output would help...

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov added the output.

Comment: Execute with `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1` environment variable set and grep output with `grep -o 'Loading CallbackModule .*search'` to inspect for duplicated loads.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I added the beginning of the logs to my question. I think 
Loading callback plugin unnamed of type old, v1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.pyc
lines represents my plugin somehow.

Comment: Yep, this must show the problem. Because the number of this line shows exactly the number of duplicated logs.

Comment: check for *.py or *.pyc or *.pyo files dangling around, if you played with renaming your plugin multiple times

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I took profile_tasks plugin from GitHub and put it manually in my code. This plugin already exists in ansible 2.0 however, I want to put it manually. 

When I ran it after I added it as "profile_tasks.py", it was called twice. I found similar GitHub issues saying that if you add a plugin with an existing plugin in ansible it might be printed twice. Therefore, I changed the name of it to "profile_tasks_timer.py". After that, it started to be called three times.

Comment: I ran the ansible-playbook script many times to be sure that it is consistent and yes, each time it is run three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the git plugin in my IntelliJ IDEA. Even though I have deleted the file from IDE, it was not added to my git commit and I did not realise that in the pull request.

Therefore "profile_tasks.py" was called twice because it is a predefined plugin in ansible and ansible has duplicate logs if you have a plugin with the same name. Additionally, the third log was coming from the renamed plugin and totally 3 duplicate logs were printed. After I deleted the "profile_tasks.py" manually from the project, two of them are removed and log is printed only once as expected.